# cant import createBatchingNetworkInterface from apollo-client

Tags: node.js, vue.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to integrate graphql with my vue project.
I am following these instructions: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo

I have npm installed 'apollo-client' as required, but for some reason i can't import 'createBatchingNetworkInterface'.

this is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ApolloClient, createBatchingNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
```

and this is the index.d.ts file of my apollo-client:

```
export { print as printAST } from 'graphql/language/printer';
export { ObservableQuery, FetchMoreOptions, UpdateQueryOptions, ApolloCurrentResult } from './core/ObservableQuery';
export { WatchQueryOptions, MutationOptions, SubscriptionOptions, FetchPolicy, FetchMoreQueryOptions, SubscribeToMoreOptions, MutationUpdaterFn } from './core/watchQueryOptions';
export { NetworkStatus } from './core/networkStatus';
export * from './core/types';
export { ApolloError } from './errors/ApolloError';
import ApolloClient, { ApolloClientOptions } from './ApolloClient';
export { ApolloClientOptions };
export { ApolloClient };
export default ApolloClient;
```

I don't see here the 'createBatchingNetworkInterface' desired object.

I don't know what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're using Apollo Client 2.0.You should downgrade to an older version (1.9.3) to continue using network interfaces, including the batching one.

The newest version of the client uses Links instead. You can check out the upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/Upgrade.md) if you are interested. you can still batch requests in 2.0 using [apollo-link-batch-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-batch-http).

Comment: Here's a new link for the upgrade guide: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/recipes/2.0-migration.md